# jquery countdown plugin with multiple ajax call?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

im trying to send multiple calls to php file through jquery ajax and print a count down timer using this Jquery plugin [CountDown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.timer').each(function () {
        var time = null;
        $.ajax({
            url: 'serverTime.php',
            async: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (text) {
                time = new Date(text);

            },
            error: function (http, message, exc) {
                time = new Date();
            }
        });
        $('.timer').countdown({
            until: time,
            compact: true,
            format: 'HMS'
        });
    });
})
```

and this my PHP

```
<?php
$now = time() + 9999; 
echo date("M j, Y H:i:s",$now)."\n"; 
$now1 = time() + 999; 
echo date("M j, Y H:i:s",$now1)."\n"; 
?>
```

i need to show each time printed into separated div but this is what i got

```
NaN:NaN:NaN

NaN:NaN:NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax potion need to be change

```
 $.ajax({
       url: 'serverTime.php', 
       async: false, 
       dataType: 'json', 
       success: function(text) { 
          var time1 = new Date(text.time1);
          var time2 = new Date(text,time1);

       }, 
       error: function(http, message, exc) { 
            time = new Date(); 
       }
```

Also change the php code

```
 <?php
  $now = time() + 9999; 
  $now1 = time() + 999; 
  echo json_encode(array('time1' => date("M j, Y H:i:s",$now1),'time2' => date("M j, Y H:i:s",$now2)));
 ?>
```